# In Cairo (or any SVG library) how can I draw a line/path with a continuously changing width?

Tags: python, svg, drawing, cairo

In Cairo (the SVG library) I am able to draw line segments, but I am having trouble drawing line segments with continuously changing width.

```
import cairo
from cairo import SVGSurface, Context, Matrix
import numpy as np

WIDTH = 1024
HEIGHT = 700

s = SVGSurface('example.svg', WIDTH, HEIGHT)
c = Context(s)

# Transform to normal cartesian coordinate system
m = Matrix(yy=-1, y0=HEIGHT)
c.transform(m)

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = x*np.sin(2*pi*x)
c.move_to(0, 0)
c.set_line_width(5)
for i in range(len(y)):
    c.line_to(x[i]*10, (y[i]+1)*100)
    c.set_line_width(5-(5*(y[i]/10)))  # trying to change the width of the line here
c.save()
c.set_source_rgb(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
c.restore()
c.stroke_preserve()


# Save as a SVG and PNG
s.write_to_png('example.png')
s.finish()
```

Whatever I am doing is not working because when I open it later in Illustrator it is all one width.  Another thing I notice is that although I think I am drawing all these line segments, clearly in Illustrator it's SVG representation is a single path.  Is it possible to have a path with a "continuously" changing line width?  If so how, and if not, how do I split these line segments up so that I can have changing line width?  I hope it's possible!

[image]

Comment: As you've experienced, the width applies to the whole line, whatever you set overrides. If you want this you'd have to draw separate short line segments adjusting the width as you go along.

Comment: Another solution, since you're generating the path mathematically, is to create an enclosed path with a fill rather than an open path with stroke. You're currently generating points `p(t)` on the "centre-line" of the filled region; the filled region border would be at `p(t) ± k(t) n`, where `k(t)` is the half-width as a function of the parametric variable `t`, and `n` is the path normal.

I can describe the maths in more detail if you're interested.

Comment: That sounds interesting - if you have time and could explain more that would be helpful.